# Compare current user login name with four custom sharepoint list 2010?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, content-query-web-part, jquery-ui

I have 4 custom list (test A, Test B, Test c,test D). I need to find current user login belongs to which list in sharepoint. if current user belongs to Test b list i need to show pop up "U belong to Test b team".

Only using Javascript and Jquery in the content editor webpart.

Thanks.

Comment: So your list contains list of usernames?

Comment: yes my list contains list of user name.totally i have 4 list. i need to check in which list the user name is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can read listitem properties from following code:

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
    );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    ); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Also you can read current user login name from:

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
  var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
  $.ajax({
    url : requestUri,
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers : requestHeaders,
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
  });

  function onSuccess(data, request){
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    alert(loginName);
  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert("error");
  }
</script>
```

So you can modify the code snippets according to your business logic.

Comment: yes my list contains list of user name.totally i have 4 list. i need to check in which list the user name is present or not.

Comment: From your code i can able to find for only one list (announcements). how i need to check for four lists?

Comment: You can check one by one and replace the list name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using thrid party libraries, then I created [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) that is a JavaScript API to deal with Sharepoint.

With it (and jQuery), the code will be:

```
// we test each of the lists
$(["Test A", "Test B", "Test C", "Test D"]).each(function(i, list) {
  // we use the WHERE clause "Name = '[Me]'" where "Name" is the column name of the user
  // '[Me]' will automatically target the current user
  $SP().list(list).get({fields:"ID",where:"Name = '[Me]'",rowlimit:1}, function(data) {
    // if data.length is bigger than 0 it means we found the user in that list
    if (data.length>0) alert("You're in the list "+list)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check current login user is present in custom list or not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://azurespdev01:7491/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // var userId = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    // fieldName: "UserId"});  // U cant match user name record with current user

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;// use userid to match
    var query = '<Query>' +
    '<Where>' +
    '<Eq>' +
    '<FieldRef Name="Columname" />' +
    '<Value Type="Lookup">' + userid + '</Value>' +
    '</Eq>' +
    '</Where>' +
    '</Query>';

     $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "ListName",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='columname' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {    
    var matchFound = false; //define flag

    //loop through all rows
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    var split = ($(this).attr("ows_User"));

    var id = split.split(';')[0];
        if (userid == id) {
            matchFound = true; //set the flag to true indicating matched record
        } 
    });

    if(matchFound)
        document.getElementById("imageHolder").innerHTML="<img src='/YourImage.jpg' alt=''/>";// show ur foto
    else
        document.getElementById("imageHolder").innerHTML="<img src='/NOimage.jpg' alt=''/>";// show others foto
}
});
});

</script>
```